# Android ndk exceptions error during run time

Tags: android-ndk

I have ported some native code to android and in the run time I am getting the error

```
 A/libc(7857): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1)
```

But I am not able to find out which part of my code is throwing this error

How to have these error deatils in android ndk

Comment: Look in LogCat just below/above this line, some should be there.

Comment: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000     #01  pc 000664ac  /data/data/com.ras.mimojni/lib/libmimoLib2.so (_ZNSsC2ERKSs)  . I had looked in to the logcat . but could not find the location in my code where this exactly happening ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ndk-stack from the Android-NDK is the tool to run on the logcat output, this may give a complete stack trace if you are lucky

```
ndk-stack -sym <path> [-dump <path>]
  -sym  Contains full path to the root directory for symbols.
  -dump Contains full path to the file containing the crash dump.
        This is an optional parameter. If ommited, ndk-stack will
        read input data from stdin
See docs/NDK-STACK.html in your NDK installation tree for more details.
```

so you probably want to run

```
logcat | ndk-stack -sym <the symbol file from your project>
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, use ndk-stack.  A good guide can be found [here](http://www.codexperiments.com/android/2010/08/tips-tricks-debugging-android-ndk-stack-traces/).